# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function with Bootstrap-Slider-Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I added `gem 'bootstrap-slider-rails'` into my Rails (4.1.8) project, but I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function` when trying to call `.slider()` function on my `input`

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss

```
/*
*= require bootstrap-slider
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

html

```
<div class='panel-body'>
  <span>10</span>
  <input class='span2' data-slider-min='1000' data-slider-step='5' data-slider-value='[250,450]' id='prices' type='text' value=''>
  <span>1000</span>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#prices").slider();
});
```

Where is my error?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @MBaas I haven't picked it up for a while, but found a solution this time.

Comment: Well - I had the same symptom, but my problem was different: I had not loaded the files for jqui ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution here https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

> If there is already a JQuery plugin named slider bound to the JQuery namespace, then this plugin will take on the alternate namespace bootstrapSlider.

So, you need to change

```
$("#prices").slider();
```

To

```
$("#prices").bootstrapSlider();
```